# I don't get any output when I scrape this

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I thought of scraping the typos I made in a typing test on the following [website](https://data.typeracer.com/pit/result?id=%7Ctr:_cephas_%7C798).

This is the code I used

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

header = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36"
}

n = 798
url = f"https://data.typeracer.com/pit/result?id=|tr:_cephas_|{n}"
page = requests.get(url, headers = header)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')

for List in soup.select("div.replayWord"):
    print(List.get_text(strip=True))
```

I used different selectors and I also used the find() and find_all() function. But I couldn't get any output for this one. Please help me to figure out my problem.

Comment: The content you are looking for is dynamic render through `JS` so using`bs4` module you will be not able to extract it try out with `selenium` may be it will work!

Comment: How you found that @BhavyaParikh?

Comment: When you print `soup` you can find manually  by searching elements and even from site if you refresh scroll down to analytics part it takes few seconds to loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a python library designed to support what you need. Have a look at [requests_html](https://docs.python-requests.org/projects/requests-html/en/latest/)

install it:

```
pip install requests_html
```

add this:

```
 from requests_html import HTMLSession
```

Then this is your solution:

```py
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#import requests

header = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36"
}

n = 798
url = f"https://data.typeracer.com/pit/result?id=|tr:_cephas_|{n}"

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get(url, headers = header)
r.html.render(timeout=60)
replayWords = r.html.find("div.replayWord")

for word in replayWords:
    print(word.text)
```

Note that the first time you run this it downloads `chromium` as the rendering agent - this can take a minute.

This library also seems VERY slow on the `render` on my machine. I'm not sure if this is the site or my laptop having an off-day, but, if you can live with that delay, the output is:

```
spot
intend
must
known;
against
possible
points;
forces
being
many
```